# java web-application initialization and shutdown

Tags: java, web-applications, initialization, shutdown

I'm trying to implements initialization and shutdown of a webapp. That includes initialization and shutdown of:

- Hibernate (v3.6);
- C3P0 (v0.9.1.2);
- EHCache (v2.3.0);
- Quartz (1.8.4);
- Other tasks specific to my webapp;

Using Tomcat 5.5.30 and Java 6. My idea is to avoid resource leaking, mostly because of the redeploy of the webapp in the development environment.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually for Web initialization and shutdown, you will write a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

The steps to do this are:

1. Write a class that implements `javax.Servlet.ServletContextListener`
2. Add a tag to `web.xml` deployment descriptor to register the class you've just created
3. Deploy your application

When you deploy your application, [`contextInitialized`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) method will be called. You can place all initialization you want here. On application shutdown [`contextDestroyed`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) method will be called.

Comment: Perfect solution, it was exactly what i wanted for my web application

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible to use the HTTP Servlet instead but the listener is a better option.

You have to extend a class with [HttpServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and setting the following stuff to your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartupServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.servlets.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The class can overwrite the init and the destroy method.

Answer (score 0):

But still you want to manage your resources in such a way that they do not leak if the application crashes and normal shutdown routines are not called.